# How to remove right margin space in modern cv?

Tags: margins, moderncv

I am new to LaTeX and am preparing my resume using `moderncv` template. I changed most of the settings to suit my requirements except that I was unable to get theenter code here huge right side margin to go away.

My current LaTex souce file

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage[scale=0.9, top=1cm,paperheight=11.8in]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{1.5cm}                    

\usepackage{hyperref}                               % to use hyperlinks
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}            % hyperlinks setup
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

% personal data
\firstname{first name}
\familyname{last}
\title{MS in some univ}
\address{124 apartments}{Apt 210, some place, state, pin}    
\mobile{723 344 3344}       
\email{227@1234.edu}
\nopagenumbers{}                            
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace*{-16mm}

\section{Education}
%\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\cventry{Aug 2012 -}{Master of Science in Computer Science and Engineering}{University of 1231023}{1212 Uni123versity of }{\textit{3.6/4}}{Specilization Track: Artificial Intelligence\\ Relavent Courses: Machine Learning, Pattern Recognition, Algorithms.}
\cventry{Aug 2004 - Aug 2008}{Bachelor of Science in Computer Science and Engineering}{Jlfdsdfsdfsdf sdfsfdsf sfsfsfd sdfsdf}{another place, state}{\textit{3.7/4}}{}  

\section{Work Experience}
\cventry{Aug 2010 - Aug 2012}{Developer in abc infotech}{company}{place, country}{}{blas blah blah blah abc. I did this and that. I have done super great things in that company and then another and so on. blah. \\ Tools used: python other stuffetc.}

\section{ Recent Projects}
\cvline{}{\textbf{Comparison study of various models for digit recognition} Implemented Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression, Neural Networks, Support Vector Machine models to automatically classify digits and did a performance study of the models.}

\section{Skills}
\cvline{Languages}{\small Python, Java, Prolog, C.}
\cvline{Tools}{\small Matlab, Hadoop.}
\cvline{Others}{\small Linux, Latex, Git, Vim, Windows.}
\end{document}
```

The problem I described regarding the right side margin is as below. The address is perfectly aligned but the body is constricted all along the page and leaving huge right margin. You can see in the following cropped image

[image]

Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi Xavier, I edited my post and added MWE as you suggested. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can't see the issue, when running the example.

Comment: @egreg You are not able to reproduce the huge right margin that's coming in the pdf after as shown in the screenshot?  strange. I am using TeXworks and also tested with pdflatex command, both of which resulted in the same output.

Comment: I needed to correct your MWE for it to compile (`moderncv` already loads `hyperref` (so I had to remove `\usepackage{hyperref}` and put the `\hyperref{...}` inside `\AtBeginDocument`), but after that, I didn't notice any issue with the margins...

Comment: @Xavier This probably means that my texworks settings might be different somehow because I used the same source and produced the pdf which has margin problems. You can see the source and pdf output screenshot here http://i.imgur.com/1W9uToj.png . This seems to specific to my machine somehow but thanks for taking time and helping out. I will probably resort to some word template.Thanks, again.

Comment: You seem to be working on Ubuntu, right? Are you using the TeX Live version provided with Ubuntu, or did you do a clean manual install? Ubuntu usually ships with very outdated packages, so tracking where the bug exactly is might be very tedious. If you want to use LaTeX, I suggest you remove the texlive installed by Ubuntu and do a clean install. Check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for example on how to do this.